# Adjective for the name 'Grothendieck'

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, names

[Grothendieck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_Grothendieck) was a major mathematician in the 20th century.

I would like to know how one can use his name to talk about the content of a study.

For example in French we would say

Hi all,

> Études Grothendieckiennes

My best try to write this in English would be:

> Grothendiecian Studies

But I am not sure. What do you think? What would be the adjective for the name Grothendieck?

Comment: There should be a *k* in there.

Comment: Trivial question. Consider Newtonian, Gaussian, Hamiltonian, Fermatian. Whether you chose the -ian construction or not is a matter of opinion. For example, Caley, Wiles and Turing did not attract the suffix.

Answer (score 3):

I'd accept Wiktionary: [Grothendieckian](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Grothendieckian)

Comment: +1, definitely valid, but I would think "Grothendieck studies" would also work, just like, for example, you might find "Poe studies": https://www.press.jhu.edu/journals/poe-studies-history-theory-interpretation#:~:text=The%20editors%20wish%20to%20define%20%22Poe%20studies%22%20broadly--to,such%20as%20gothicism%2C%20detective%20fiction%2C%20symbolism%2C%20and%20metafiction.